# Laravel 5.2 make:auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, registration

I've had a problem when trying to use the `PHP artisan make:auth` function to set up my login and reg pages with the new `Laravel 5.2`. Everything seems to generate and load fine, I get to the home page, but any of the links I click on throw the same error, which is:

```
FatalThrowableError in Encrypter.php line 66:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_encrypt()
```

I've tried re-installing and setting up new routes to the pages and looked through google to try and find an answer to no avail. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Did you set the `key` option in your `config/app.php` configuration file to a 32 character, random string? I think I remember this being related...not positive but a good place to start.

Comment: Did your PHP have openssl extension?

Comment: I'll give the random string a try, and I'm not sure about the openssl extension!

Comment: There was already a 32 random key set in my .env file so I'm thinking it cant be that

Comment: Run `php -m | grep openssl` it should output `openssl` if the extension is installed or nothing if it's not. `grep` will work on Linux and OSX, so if you're on Windows just run `php -m` and check the list for `openssl`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable `openssl` on your server first.

Open your `php.ini`, and uncomment the line that reads

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Remove the semicolon to enable the dll, then restart your service.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,

I had to change the `phpForApache.ini` , and uncomment the line that reads

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```